# How to do Spatial Filter in Google Maps V3 By Using http://dev.huement.com/gmaps/arcgislink/

Tags: arcgis-10.0

The following code is deprecated in Google Maps V3 and ESRI arcgis maps, I want to update into new versions, but I am trapped in query.queryGeometry = poly1; poly1 is self-defined polygon.

```
function runtask(poly1) 
        {
            mapExtension = new esri.arcgis.gmaps.MapExtension(map);
            esri.arcgis.gmaps.Config.proxyUrl = "proxy.ashx";
            var qtask = new esri.arcgis.gmaps.QueryTask("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/0");
            var query = new esri.arcgis.gmaps.Query();
            var polygonArea = poly1.getArea();
            query.queryGeometry = poly1;
            query.returnGeometry = true;
            query.outFields = ['POP2000', 'HOUSEHOLDS', 'BLOCK'];
            qtask.execute(query, false, displayStats);
        }

        function displayStats(fset, error) {
            if (error) 
            {
                alert("Error " + error.code + ": " + (error.message || (error.details && error.details.join(" ")) || "Unknown error"));
                return;
            }
            var features = fset.features;
            var popTotal = 0;
            var houseTotal = 0;
            var blockTotal = 0; 
            for (var x = 0; x < features.length; x++) {
                popTotal = popTotal + features[x].attributes['POP2000'];
                houseTotal = houseTotal + features[x].attributes['HOUSEHOLDS'];
                blockTotal = blockTotal + 1;
            }
            if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
                document.getElementById('Label1').innerText = popTotal;
                document.getElementById('Label2').innerText = houseTotal;
                document.getElementById('Label8').innerText = blockTotal;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('Label1').textContent = popTotal;
                document.getElementById('Label2').textContent = houseTotal;
                document.getElementById('Label8').textContent = blockTotal;
            }

            var qtask2 = new esri.arcgis.gmaps.QueryTask("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/1");
            var query2 = new esri.arcgis.gmaps.Query();
            query2.queryGeometry = poly1;
            query2.returnGeometry = true;
            // The default spatial relationship is esri.arcgis.gmaps.SpatialRelationship.INTERSECTS
            query2.outFields = ["AGE_UNDER5", "AGE_5_17", "AGE_18_21", "AGE_22_29", "AGE_30_39", "AGE_40_49", "AGE_50_64", "AGE_65_UP"];
            qtask2.execute(query2, false, setBlockGroupPolyArr);
            draw(centre); 
        }

        function setBlockGroupPolyArr(fset) 
        {
            blockGroupPolyArr = fset.features;
            for (var i = 0, il = blockGroupPolyArr.length; i < il; i++) 
            {
                displayBlockGroupPolys(blockGroupPolyArr[i]);
            }
        }

        function displayBlockGroupPolys(blockGroupPolyArr) 
        {
            censusPolyArr = [];
            var feature = blockGroupPolyArr;
            var att = feature.attributes;
            var age_under5 = parseInt(att.AGE_UNDER5);
            var age_5_17 = parseInt(att.AGE_5_17);
            var age_18_21 = parseInt(att.AGE_18_21);
            var age_22_29 = parseInt(att.AGE_22_29);
            var age_30_39 = parseInt(att.AGE_30_39);
            var age_40_49 = parseInt(att.AGE_40_49);
            var age_50_64 = parseInt(att.AGE_50_64);
            var age_65_up = parseInt(att.AGE_65_UP);
            total = age_under5 + age_5_17 + age_18_21 + age_22_29 + age_30_39 + age_40_49 + age_50_64 + age_65_up;
            age_under5 = (age_under5 / total) * 100;
            age_5_17 = (age_5_17 / total) * 100;
            age_18_21 = (age_18_21 / total) * 100;
            age_22_29 = (age_22_29 / total) * 100;
            age_30_39 = (age_30_39 / total) * 100;
            age_40_49 = (age_40_49 / total) * 100;
            age_50_64 = (age_50_64 / total) * 100;
            age_65_up = (age_65_up / total) * 100;
            var infoWindowOption = {
                content: "<div style='width:325px; height:125px;'><b>Total 2000 Census Block Population is: " + total + ".</b><br />The age breakdown is as follows: <br />"
                    + "<img  src='http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=300x100&chd=t:"
                    + age_under5 + "," + age_5_17 + "," + age_18_21 + "," + age_22_29 + ","
                    + age_30_39 + "," + age_40_49 + "," + age_50_64 + "," + age_65_up + "&chs=300x100&chl=<5 ("
                    + Math.round(age_under5) + "%)|5-17 ("
                    + Math.round(age_5_17) + "%)|18-21 ("
                    + Math.round(age_18_21) + "%)|22-29 ("
                    + Math.round(age_22_29) + "%)|30-39 ("
                    + Math.round(age_30_39) + "%)|40-49 ("
                    + Math.round(age_40_49) + "%)|50-64 ("
                    + Math.round(age_50_64) + "%)|>65 ("
                    + Math.round(age_65_up) + "%)' /></div>"
            };
            var overlayOptionsPoly = {fillOpacity: 0.05};
            censusPoly = mapExtension.addToMap(feature, overlayOptionsPoly, infoWindowOption);
            censusPolyArr.push(censusPoly);
        }
```

**My new version runtask(poly1) is as below, I do not know how to do spatial filter by poly1 as above.**

```
function runtask(poly1) {
            gmaps.ags.Config.proxyUrl = "proxy.ashx";
            var url = 'http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer';
            layer = new gmaps.ags.Layer(url + '/0'); ///POLYGON layer
            var style = {
                fillColor: '#333388',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
                strokeWeight: 1,
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                zIndex: 0
            };
            var params = {
                returnGeometry: true,
                where: "ObjectID=2",
                //geometry: -179.619162909091,71.3629552727273,
                outFields: ['POP2000', 'HOUSEHOLDS', 'BLOCK'],
                overlayOptions: style
            };

            //layer.query(params, setBlockGroupPolyArr);
            layer.query(params, displayStats);
            //draw(centre);
        }
           [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

**I want to have the following blue polygon within poly1:**
[image]